# Accessing type parameters of outer type

Tags: generics, types, nested, kotlin

In Kotlin, we can define nested interfaces. If the outer interface is generic (here just to simulate a proper `Self` meta-type, but one can imagine other uses), can I refer to its type parameter from the inner type?

That is, I want to achieve (an equivalent of) this:

```
interface JsonRepresentable<Self: JsonRepresentable<Self>> {
    fun toJson(): String

    interface Companion {
        operator fun invoke(json:String): Self?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. An interface can't be a non-static inner class, which is a platform constrain that can't be overcame by Kotlin. 
I know it would be pretty useful to constrain how the companion object should be, but this haven't been considered yet. I don't know if JetBrains will ever take this suggestion seriously.

In your attempt, those two interfaces are NOT related at all, except that you can find `KClass<Compaion>` in `JsonRepresentable::class.nestedClasses`. The relationship between these interfaces can be compared to the relationship between a Java static inner class and its declaring class.